# Fetch data from cfg file

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, filesystems

My file, `config.cfg` contains:

---

```
{'lemon@user.com': [10, 13, 'lemon', 2],
 'leonn@user.com': [12, 24, 'leonn', 4],
 'brade@user.com': [15, 48, 'brade', 6],
 'pluto@user.com': [11, 12, 'pluto', 4],
 'daren@user.com': [19, 85, 'daren', 8],
 'maxon@user.com': [12, 14, 'maxon', 3]}
```

I want to fetch `'daren'` by highest number `85`.

Can you please tell me how to the retrieve highest number and then its associated name?

Comment: Any code you have tried that we can start with?

Comment: Ho did you create the config file? Please show the code so we don't have to reinvent or guess

Answer (score 0):

If you replace single quotes (`'`) with double quotes (`"`), your config file becomes json-compliant. Then, you can parse it using `json` library:

```
import json

f = open("config.cfg")
cfg = json.load(f)

largest = 0
selected = None
for item in cfg:
    if cfg[item][1] > largest:
        largest = cfg[item][1]
        selected = item

print selected
```